# Why should you FanOut when building a Activity Feed

Tags: mysql, database, feed, nosql

I'm looking into the logistics of building an Activity Feed, similar to that of Facebook, or Twitter's timeline.

There are tons of answers here on StackOverlfow and on Quora and other articles I've found on google that describe fanning out on read or write. It all makes sense. You record all the activity in one main activity table/collection, and then at some point, write a copy of that data to separate, appropriate tables for each user.

What I dont completely understand is why is there a need for a fanout? That is, Why is there a need to record the activity on individual user feeds? Is there a reason why you cant just use one activity table/collection? It would have appropriate indexes, and have the acting user's ID. And then, when someone wants to see their activity stream, just query the activity stream for users that the current user is following.

I understand that this may not be as efficient since activities outnumber actual objects in the database a few times over. That is, there are might be 100 posts in a database, but over 1,000 actions on posts, thus queries may be slow on the activity table/collection when row numbers get pretty high.

But wouldnt this work? Cant you just scale the database so it can handle queries more efficiently? Is there really a **need** for fanning out?

Answer (score 0):

Not necessary to fan-out always, but the decision is depends on many factors.

For eg. Twitter does both but Facebook follows fan-out-on-load.

As you can imagine, Facebook's activity stream is much more complex than Twitter's. FB needs to apply lot of filters/privacy settings per user/group basis, hence it make sense for them to pull and build the stream on-the fly. Their TAO graph infrastructure (Graphing on top of MySQL + Caching) makes it easy for them to build and fetch the feeds quite fast for each user.